# Most efficient way to pass parameters to the super class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance

What's the best way to solve this issue?
I love the way that we can define attributes in the constructor and TSC does all the magic for us to resolve the resp. lines of code in order to assign the values to the props in JavaScript - what I did here with department.

But I'm curious if there is something useful for inheritance as well?!
Is there a way to let's say init a subclass with all attributes and pass them along to the super call without repeating all the properties here?

I would not like to manually put there /* all the other attributes of the base class*/ in order to init the class and satisfy the super call.

Thanks in advance and regards.

```
class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(public department: number, /* all the other attributes of the base class*/ ){
    super( /* all the other attributes of the base class*/ );
  }
}

let myEmp = new Employee(1, "James"); // Base class
let myMng = new Manager (101, 2, "Jane" ); // Subclass
```

**UPDATE:**
After some of your helpful feedback to bring me on some other tracks regarding TypeScript, I ended up here. Gonna try to tweak it a bit to get rid of explicitly naming and listing the superclass members in the super-call.
It would be nice and helpful to hear some thoughts on this approach.

```
class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(public department: number, empData: Employee) {
    super(empData.id, empData.name);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE #2 + ANSWER:**
After some helpful hint from @AluanHaddad and some deep-diving into **Utility Types from TSC**, that's what I was looking for.

Thanks to all of you!

```
class Employee {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}
}

class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(
    public department: number,
    ...superClassData: ConstructorParameters<typeof Employee >
  ) {
    super(...superClassData);
  }
}

let myEmp = new Employee(1, "James"); // Base class
let myMng = new Manager (101, 2, "Jane" ); // Subclass
```

Comment: Instead of positional arguments to the constructors, use an object with named properties. Since the "options" object will be a super type of the type of the options object for the base class you can just pass the whole thing.

Comment: That's freaking epic, thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I wrote it up as an answer, feel free to accept if it works for you (little green checkmark next to my answer)

Comment: I do like the object approach. Very elegant. You could also use `constructor(department: number, ...args: ConstructorParameters<Employee>) { super(...args); }`

Comment: The approach with those Utility Types is incredible, @aluan! Very much appreciated! Regards! :)

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful:-) I should add an answer perhaps

Comment: I've mentioned you in the answer ...or at least tried to, can't see a hyperlink for my @ :D anyway, I added the solution, which became my favorite, btw

Regards and thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of positional arguments to the constructors, use an object with named properties. Since the "options" object will be a super type of the type of the options object for the base class you can just pass the whole thing:

```
interface FooArgs {
  a: number
  b: string
}

class Foo {
  public a: number;
  public b: string;

  constructor(args: FooArgs) {
    this.a = args.a;
    this.b = args.b;
  }
}

interface BarArgs extends FooArgs {
  c: number
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  public c: number;
  
  constructor(args: BarArgs) {
    super(args);
    this.c = args.c;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0EEoHMDOyA3gFDLJwBcyIArgLYBG0Zyj1+YUouJAviRIIANnHyEM6YqwAOtRsOAIK1Ok2gBuWfMXL2yTtxC4trBOhCHaCMOigAKOHnzVJOAgEpp5cmAAWwPgAdHDIALwUziFaPsj+gUGM4ZEEiTHIAgIkoJCwiCgAQk7uhBAAHpAgACYSmCXeyAiqDMxQ-IIiYoRFUMjllTVomA1yCkqNzepQ6WYWVjZ2js7UPSVepLH4tDLQS57pvgHByhFOqQjpmYJAA)

This also has the added benefit of making your args more human-readable at the call site where you `new` up these objects:

```
const John = new Employee({ age: 32, salary: 60000, name: 'John Smith' });
const Mary = new Manager({ age: 45, salary: 90000, name: 'Mary Brown', directReports: 7 });
```

Comment: Is there a difference here between using `type` or `interface`?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky you could use types with an intersection `&` instead of `extend`ing interfaces, there are some subtle differences but they don't really matter here (I see you did that in your answer).

Comment: I just realized that `Foo` could actually use `implements FooArgs`.

Comment: This looks cool. Is there a way to rewrite the whole thing, so I do not have to manually assign the object properties? I mean the way you can use the properties in the constructor in combination with access modifiers.

Comment: There's not really a good shorthand for that, because there's no type-safe way to do it

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky you could do that, but it isn't really necessary and depending on the domain could even be a mistake

Comment: What do you think of this approach? Though I'm forced to use positonal arguments, I kinda keep my type safety, I think. Plus, using the resp. IDE like VS Code it points out what kinda fields being addressed, especially when using the resp. comments, so readability is  there as well. Currently trying to spread the object into its parameters, so I can avoid explicitly listing and naming the params on the super call.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76828710/6167246

Comment: ...that would be (in a sense) using object composition over inheritance which is totally valid and arguably better. Honestly you might be better off using a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) instead of a subclass here, but it's hard to say for toy example code.

Comment: Cleaning up the answer / question mess I created. Code of  the dead link above:
 
`class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor(public department: number, empData: Employee) {
    super(empData.id, empData.name);
  }
}` is now appended to my question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage *parameter object* pattern here. Instead of passing many parameters by one pass single parameter wuth multiple fields.

```
  type EmployeeParams = {
    // superclass params
  }

  type ManagerParams = {
    department: number
  } & EmployeeParams;

  class Employee {
    // declare all the fields
    constructor(params: EmployeeParams){
      // assign all the fields
    }
  }

  class Manager extends Employee {
    department: number;
    constructor(params: ManagerParams){
      super(params);
      this.department = params.department;
    }
  }
```

Note that you need now explicitly declare separate fields on the class.

Answer (score 1):

The following two code examples utilize the [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) and type declarations for class-specific parameter-configurations.

One could [go either with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBBC2YBsD2IIQMJIHYDMCWA5lALxQDeAUFFPhAgCYD6AjAFxQDOwATnlgQBoqNPHSYAmdlgCusAEYRuQgL4VQkKLACGWLQUWZchEuWHV6EMFu7BYELMCmyFSisqgAyGPGSoM2fAIAbgoKAGMELQ4OKABRHxQ0U2owaTkEPDCRMRZ2Ll5+EJS0jKzaBkZJKBl5RRDhMOx86TDgJG4ACjJsiuYBHokoZVY4RET-IwIASlMzKGAACzwOADpypmYTdZYi6nml1e3xLdEK8V3VVXDI6KgAWR09RRgAD2B7ehj4sb9kqFT0pkoBYrDY7A4nLVuPVqI0sM1Wu0usDLNZbPZgP0VtjuBAuIZAkNWNpdPpuATCDNKHtONJIJ1cfiApSYXtFssViC0eDgCYuWCMRc3KE4VxNI8ySYsBAAO73CWKZH89EQqDMcT9I7sDUDXJQABEOCQSH1Qym9VFSAQEBWyAIyJJT24ZpCQA) ...

```ts
type employeeConfig = {
  field_1: string,
  field_2: number,
}
type managerConfig = {
    department: number,
} & employeeConfig;

class Employee {
  public field_1: string;
  public field_2: number;

  constructor({ field_1, field_2 }:employeeConfig) {

    this.field_1 = field_1;
    this.field_2 = field_2;
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
  public department: number;

  constructor({ department, ...restConfig }:managerConfig) {
    super(restConfig);

    this.department = department;
  }
}

const manager = new Manager({ department: 12, field_2: 2, field_1: "foo" });

console.log({ manager });
```

... [or even with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBBC2YBsD2IIQMJIHYDMCWA5lALxQDeAUFFPhAgCYD6AjAFxQDOwATnlgQBoqNPHSYAmdlgCusAEYRuQgL4VQkKLACGWLQUWZchEuWHV6EMFu7BYELMCmyFSisqgAyGPGSoM2fAIAbgoKAGMELQ4OKABRHxQ0U2ow7C5uaTDgJG4AClSjAlY4RET-QoBKUzMoAHk5ACsILIA6KI5CLFzgAAs8DgEoAsCKkOpVVXDI6KgAWR09RRgAD2B7ehj40r9kobSeTOy8sigLKxs7B0GWm+4ILkNAqGVWbV19bkfCKspqag5pJA8ncHgFviEavUmq12p1un0BuRTpZrLZ7MBnqNhBNQgUuJoFh8TFgIAB3OaExS5E5nVGXRxQZjiQa0BiMSRQZkiMQsdgAIhwSCQfMxELxSAQEBayAI1IJ7yWyixQA) ...

```ts
type employeeConfig = {
  field_1: string,
  field_2: number,
}
type managerConfig = {
    department: number,
} & employeeConfig;

class Employee {
  constructor(config:employeeConfig) {

    Object.assign(this, config);
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor({ department, ...restConfig }:managerConfig) {
    super(restConfig);

    Object.assign(this, { department });
  }
}

const manager = new Manager({ department: 12, field_2: 2, field_1: "foo" });

console.log({ manager });
```

The latter is more flexible in terms of the `config` but one needs to sacrifice the explicit declaration of any public class fields.

Comment: Cool, never seen this aspect of using TypeScript. Thanks for providing this alternative way.

Cheers.